# Getting neighbor´s element in xml archive with Python ElementTree

Tags: python-3.x

I got a big problem managing data in xml archives in python. I need the value in the tag ValorConta1 but I only have the value in NumeroConta which is child of PlanoConta.

```xml
<InfoFinaDFin>
  <NumeroIdentificadorInfoFinaDFin>15501</NumeroIdentificadorInfoFinaDFin>
  ...
  <PlanoConta>
    <NumeroConta>2.02.01</NumeroConta>
  </PlanoConta>
  ...
  <ValorConta1>300</ValorConta1>
```

The code I write:

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

InfoDin = ET.parse('arquivos_xml/InfoFinaDFin.xml')

target_element_value = '2.01.01'
passivo = InfoDin.findall('.//PlanoConta[NumeroConta="' + target_element_value +'"]/../ValorConta1')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
from simplified_scrapy import SimplifiedDoc
html = '''
<InfoFinaDFin>
      <NumeroIdentificadorInfoFinaDFin>15501</NumeroIdentificadorInfoFinaDFin>
      ...
      <PlanoConta>
          <NumeroConta>2.02.01</NumeroConta>
      </PlanoConta>
      ...
      <ValorConta1>300</ValorConta1>
</InfoFinaDFin>
'''
doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
# print (doc.select('PlanoConta>NumeroConta>text()'))
# print (doc.select('ValorConta1>text()'))
ele = doc.NumeroConta.parent.getNext('ValorConta1')
# or 
ele = doc.getElementByTag('ValorConta1',start='</NumeroConta>')
print (ele.text)
```

Result:

```
300
```

Here are more examples:https://github.com/yiyedata/simplified-scrapy-demo/tree/master/doc_examples

Comment: Thank for your help but I was not very clear in the question. I need to find the ValorConta1 using the NumeroConta for searching the right ValorConta1 for result

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get it right. I updated the answer to see if it meets your needs